# Error trying to parse settings in Sublime Text 2.0.2

Tags: sublimetext2

I am new to Sublime Text, and I haven't been able to fix or find an answer to this problem anywhere.
I just installed `Sublime Text`, and in the beginning it worked fine. Then I tried to change some settings under Preferences-> Settings User, e.g. font size. When I saved, it returned the error:

> Error trying to parse settings: Expected string in C:\Users\Michael\AppData\Roaming\Sublime Text 2\Packages\User\Preferences.sublime-settings:18:1

(Where my ST packages are installed)
Now, whenever I try to open Sublime Text 2, it displays the same error message, and will not run.
I uninstalled and re-installed ST, and the problem remains (after I try to change my preferences).
I am running `Sublime Text 2.0.2` on Windows 7. 
Any insights into how to fix this problem (or better yet, why this problem emerged in the first place) would be most welcome.

Edit: This is the contents of the preference file (I don't know how to upload the file itself, if it is even possible)

```jason
// Settings in here override those in "Default/Preferences.sublime-settings", and
// are overridden in turn by file type specific settings.
// "User/Preferences.sublime-settings", which overrides the settings in here.
//
// Settings may also be placed in file type specific options files, for
// example, in Packages/Python/Python.sublime-settings for python files.
{
    // Sets the colors used within the text area
    "color_scheme": "Packages/Color Scheme - Default/Monokai.tmTheme",

    // Note that the font_face and font_size are overriden in the platform
    // specific settings file, for example, "Preferences (Linux).sublime-settings".
    // Because of this, setting them here will have no effect: you must set them
    // in your User File Preferences.
    "font_face": "",
    "font_size": 10,
}
```

Comment: Could you post your `Preferences.sublime-settings` file? Probably there is an error in the file.

Comment: As you can see, there is not much content in the preferences file, which is the most annoying part for me.

Comment: This is the complete file; according to some posts, the 18:1 refers to line 18,column 1, however, there seems to be no line 18.

Comment: I added the missing parenthesis to the end, and still no change; it still returns the error message. Currently it will only run if I delete everything within the {}.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove the last comma. Change:

`"font_size": 10,`

to:

`"font_size": 10`

Comment: Thanks, after deleting everything else and only changing the font size, (and the comma behind it), it worked!

Answer (score 0):

I've just run into the same issue and I fixed it by:

- Validate JSON is valid
- Ensure file encoding is "UTF-8" (File > Save with encoding...)